# jQuery when NOT selecting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to write "if users do not select a form whose id is 'id-1'" as follows, but this works as if if-statement is passed. What could be wrong?

```js
    $(document).on("keyup",
      function(p_k) {
        var target = $(this);
        if (target.is("id-1")) {} else {
          //do this ...
        }
      }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Chat#index</h1>

<ul id="chat_area">
</ul>
<input id="id-1" class='form-control' type="text">
```

Comment: `if(target.attr("id") == '-1')`

Comment: Could you possibly show us the html?

Comment: I added the html part. thanks.

Comment: target.is("#id-1") - you are missing the id hash

Comment: though it does not work now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you were attempting to add an event handler to document (which by itself does not fire events of "keyup".

Secondly, your syntax for checking the ID was off.

See the demo:

```js
$("input").on("keyup",
  function(event) 
  {
    var target = $(this);

    if (target.attr("id") == "id-1") 
    {
        console.log("Input with ID of id-1 accessed");
    } else 
    {
        console.log("Input with a different ID accessed");
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Chat#index</h1>

<ul id="chat_area">
</ul>
<input id="id-1" class='form-control' type="text">
```